# cURL query to return the redirected url is not working on every occurence

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch the redirected url from a url. For this I have used cURL function of PHP. The issue is sometimes it's working sometimes it's not. It's a very strange issue, which I can't figure out the root of.

```
$urlt='http://idealo.fr/go/511632138.html?categoryId=12313&pos=1&price=1459.95&productid=4583512&sid=26246&type=offer';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlt);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Must be set to true so that PHP follows any "Location:" header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$urnt = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL
curl_close($ch);
echo $urnt."<b>1st one</b><br />";
```

Sometimes it returns the exact redirected url and sometimes its returning the base url itself. Can anyone please indicate me the exact reason behind this?

Comment: why not check to see if the correct information is given to you and then either re-do the request or process the data given accordingly

Comment: Do you get different behaviours for the same original URL, or is it that some URLs do get your the final URL after redirect, and some not? If the latter, can you provide an example of such an URL? Have you check that it's actually an HTTP redirect (rather than a `meta refresh` or Javascript-based redirect)? What's the response you get (status code, headers, body)? Are you actually getting the "final" URL's results?

Comment: First thing I saw when I visited the page was a captcha call that was specifically there to stop bots from scraping the site.

Comment: @J_D...its not asking for any captch...

Comment: @jcaron...thats a nice point...yes i checked it and it returns the same base url...and sometimes its returning me the redirected url